# Python: How to merge 3 functions into one (for generating number counter)

Tags: python

I have below 3 separate functions, that i am using in different places of my code according their category.. Basically i want to generate different sequence numbering. Calling my function 'AppleNum'  starts with 002 as shown below, and different sequence numbering for function 'BananaNum' (it starts with 005) and so on.

My question is, how to put these 3 separate functions in single function or class, so that when i call 'Apple' i get numbers incremented from 002 and if call 'Orange' i get numbers incremented from 009.. (also if there is any possibility to set maximum number for the counter, so that it starts from minimum value.)

```
Apple = 2
def AppleNum():
    global Apple
    Apple += 1
    return str(Apple).zfill(3)

Banana = 5
def BananaNum():
    global Banana
    Banana += 1
    return str(Banana).zfill(3)

Orange = 9
def OrangeNum():
    global Orange
    Orange += 1
    return str(Orange).zfill(3)
```

`Expected output:`

```
Imagine a single function that have all above, and if call `function(Apple)` --> gives 003, and increments starts from there.

at same time if i call `function(Orange)` ---> gives 010 and increment starts from there.
```

This is just a sample code, i have 12-15 categories in my original piece of code.. Hence i dont want to write 12 separate functions.

Please help me..

(Appreciate your help if there is any possibility to set max number, that means if counter reaches 9999, counter starts from their minimum number again.)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a dict to store your functions:

```
my_f = {'Apple': AppleNum, 'Orange': OrangeNum, 'Banana' :OrangeNum}

def fruits(fruit):
    return my_f[fruit]()
```

---

here is a better way of how to set your counter to max 999:

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(lambda : cycle(range(1000)))

def fruits(f):
    return f'{next(count[f])}'.zfill(3)
```

any fruit  that is used with `fruits` function will be automatically registred and will have a max counter of 999, once you get to the max value the couter will be again recycled to 0

if you want to set your minim values you could use:

```
from itertools import cycle

count = {'Apple': cycle(range(2,1000)),  'Banana': cycle(range(5,1000)), 'Orange': cycle(range(9,1000))}
def fruits(f):
    return f'{next(count[f])}'.zfill(3)
```

Comment: Thanks Kederrac for response..In the last solution (using min values) i need not define global variables if use "fruit_min_value = {'Apple': 1, 'Banana': 5, 'Orange': 9}"..right???

Comment: @Maria yes, using global variables it is not the best practice

Comment: @Maria I've updated my last answer, that variable  `fruit_min_value ` it is not used, the minim values are set in `count`,  will recycle your min-max interval automatically

Answer (score 1):

Using a class with name and default min and max

```
class FruitCounter():
  def __init__(self, name, begin = 0, max_count = 9999):
    self.name = name
    self.count = begin
    self.max_count = max_count

  def incr(self):
    if self.count <= self.max_count:
      self.count += 1
    return str(self.count).zfill(3)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Test**

```
# Instantiate fruit in loop and increment
for fruit in [FruitCounter('Apple', 2, 4), FruitCounter('Banana', 5, 7), FruitCounter('Orange', 9)]:
  for i in range(10):
    print(f'Incrementing {fruit} {fruit.incr()}')
```

**Output**

```
Incrementing Apple 003
Incrementing Apple 004
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Apple 005
Incrementing Banana 006
Incrementing Banana 007
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Banana 008
Incrementing Orange 010
Incrementing Orange 011
Incrementing Orange 012
Incrementing Orange 013
Incrementing Orange 014
Incrementing Orange 015
Incrementing Orange 016
Incrementing Orange 017
Incrementing Orange 018
Incrementing Orange 019
```

Comment: HI DarrylG, thanks for response.. i didnt understand max_count = -1. I tried change it to 2, but i found no difference in output..

Comment: @Maria--`max_count = -1` was to cause it to ignore it in that case.  I modified code to just make max_count a large number by default (i.e. 9999) instead to be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite straightforward. Here's the simplest way to do it:

```py
Apple = 2
Banana = 5
Orange = 9

def fn(case):
  global Apple, Banana, Orange

  if case == "Apple":
    Apple += 1
    return str(Apple).zfill(3)
  elif case == "Banana":
    Banana += 1
    return str(Banana).zfill(3)
  elif case == "Orange":
    Orange += 1
    return str(Orange).zfill(3)
  return
```

For a maximum, just include some constant "original value" variables and then check if any value is greater than the maximum when you increment it, Then reset if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, this should seem to do the trick

```py
Apple = 2
Orange = 9
Banana = 5
def fruit_inc(fruit):
    global Apple, Orange, Banana
    if fruit == "Apple":
        Apple += 1
        return str(Apple).zfill(3)
    elif fruit == "Orange":
        Orange += 1
        return str(Orange).zfill(3)
    elif fruit == "Banana":
        Banana += 1
        return str(Banana).zfill(3)
    else:
        print("Fruit is invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class called Fruit (for instance) and then instantiate your different fruits:

```
class Fruit():
    amount = 0
    index = ''
    def increment(self):
        self.amount += 1
        self.index = str(self.amount).zfill(3)

banana = Fruit()
banana.increment()

apple = Fruit()
apple.increment()
apple.increment()
apple.increment()

print (banana.index, 'bananas') # prints 001 bananas
print (apple.index, 'apples')   # prints 003 apples
```